# Is it possible to use AWS CloudFront for PHP files?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to load PHP files such as `index.php` using AWS CloudFront.

The documentation states -

> Create a web distribution if you want to:
>
> Speed up distribution of static and dynamic content, for example,
>   .html, .css, .php, and graphics files. Distribute media files using
>   HTTP or HTTPS. Add, update, or delete objects, and submit data from
>   web forms. Use live streaming to stream an event in real time.

However, when I upload PHP files to the relative CloudFront bucket it ends up downloading the file and opening it. How will allow me to host PHP files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when I upload PHP files to the relative CloudFront bucket

There is no such thing as a *CloudFront bucket*, so you are likely referring to an S3 bucket, configured behind CloudFront as an origin.

CloudFront works with dynamic content, such as might be generated with PHP, but the PHP site needs to be hosted on a server that supports it -- not S3.

> You can host a static website on Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). On a static website, individual webpages include static content. They might also contain client-side scripts. By contrast, **a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP**, JSP, or ASP.NET. **Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

See [AWS Web Site Solutions](https://aws.amazon.com/websites/) for options for hosting sites involving static or dynamic content, bearing in mind that PHP requires a solution supporting server-side scripting and dynamic content, so not all solutions presented there (including S3) will fit your needs...  but these are all compatible with CloudFront -- which is only tasked with *delivering* the rendered content, not the original rendering.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront is designed to serve content to end users and not execute your code. Your PHP files would be on an EC2 instance running PHP and a webserver (Apache, Nginx) which you could then put behind CloudFront to get the benefits. This would then generate the HTML for CloudFront to serve. CloudFront itself does not handle the processing and just deals with the static HTML. When using CloudFront with S3 it will serve up the content directly to the end user.

I am not quite sure where you found that snippet but the introduction does not seem to list .php for me.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html

> Amazon CloudFront is a web service that speeds up distribution of your
>   static and dynamic web content, such as .html, .css, .js, and image
>   files, to your users.

Comment: This is incorrect, but to your credit, that sentence in the documentation is not as clear as it could be.  CloudFront has had support for dynamic content [since 2012](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-dynamic-content/).  The problem is that OP didn't mention that they are also apparently using S3, which doesn't support dynamic content or any kind of server-side scripting.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I guess it depends on how you look at it. To me the result of the PHP script is what CloudFront handles which at that point is just HTML. CloudFront would treat the responses the same as if it was a static html file as it just serves the result. I have hopefully made my answer more clear.

Comment: Yes, CloudFront just serves the result, requiring a back-end (origin) server that can actually execute the PHP code... but the question implies an attempt to use S3 as the origin, which won't work with PHP (for reasons unrelated to CloudFront).  The text quoted in the question is from the CloudFront console, when you're walking through the wizard to [create a distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html#GettingStartedCreateDistribution).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have ignored that snippet of text of that page so many times. It probably should be clearer but I guess it does not specify how you give CloudFront the content because ultimately it does not care. The user just needs to set up there own way to render the PHP and not use S3.